# AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute '__discord_app_commands_guild_only__'

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot which sends the input received through a modal to a person having a specific role. However, I'm getting an AttributeError with the message "'Interaction' object has no attribute 'discord_app_commands_guild_only'" when I try to call this method

Here is the code

```
class Mymodal(discord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self, title: str):
        super().__init__(title=title)
        self.add_item(discord.ui.TextInput(label="Your response", placeholder="Enter your response"))
        self.submitted = False  # Initialize submitted flag to False

    
    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.interactions):
        if self.submitted:
            return  # Prevent duplicate responses

        role_name = "moderator"  # Replace with the actual role name
        role = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name=role_name)
        member_name = interaction.user.name
        response = self.children[0].value
        await interaction.response.send_message("Your response has been submitted.", ephemeral=True)
     
        async def send_to_moderators():
            if interaction.guild:
                for member in interaction.guild.members:
                    await role.send(f"A support ticket has been submitted by {member_name}. Response: {response}")
        
        discord.app_commands.guild_only(interaction).loop.create_task(send_to_moderators())
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    discord.app_commands.guild_only(interaction).loop.create_task(send_to_moderators())
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\myc49\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 2430, in guild_only
    return inner(func)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\myc49\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 2422, in inner
    f.__discord_app_commands_guild_only__ = True  # type: ignore # Runtime attribute assignment
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute '__discord_app_commands_guild_only__'
```